# How to show line break to special character in html

Tags: html

I have a string which contains special ascii character which is carriage return (hex: D) and Line Feed (hex: A) , something like "abc abc", which have (DA) between "abc", now I want to show the line break in html.Is it possible?

Comment: please provide a clearer example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **only HTML**, use a `<pre>` tag to display:

```html
<pre>ABC
ABC</pre>
```

Using the CSS property `white-space: pre-wrap;` you can make it:

```css
div {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>ABC
ABC</div>
```